# Sed add newline before last occurrence of brace?

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, command-line

I want to insert a new line before the last occurrence of brace. My text file looks like that

```
 "accounts": {
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000008": { "builtin": { "name": "alt_bn128_pairing", "activate_at": "0x0", "pricing": { "alt_bn128_pairing": { "base": 100000, "pair": 80000 } } } },
    "0x00Ea169ce7e0992960D3BdE6F5D539C955316432": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376" }
 }
```

So what I want to do is adding a new `account` through sed script.

Please note that the new account will be specified with a variable, something like:

```
"$ACCOUNT_ADDR": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376" }
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is the wrong tool for this job. One of the right tools is `jq`.

```
% cat wibble.json
{
"accounts": {
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000008": { "builtin": { "name": "alt_bn128_pairing", "activate_at": "0x0", "pricing": { "alt_bn128_pairing": { "base": 100000, "pair": 80000 } } } },
    "0x00Ea169ce7e0992960D3BdE6F5D539C955316432": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376" }
}
}
% ACCOUNT_ADDR="0xdeadbeeffeefdface0badd00dcacad0d0eeeeeeee"
% jq '."accounts"."'"${ACCOUNT_ADDR}"'"."balance"="42"' wibble.json
{
  "accounts": {
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000008": {
      "builtin": {
        "name": "alt_bn128_pairing",
        "activate_at": "0x0",
        "pricing": {
          "alt_bn128_pairing": {
            "base": 100000,
            "pair": 80000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "0x00Ea169ce7e0992960D3BdE6F5D539C955316432": {
      "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376"
    },
    "0xdeadbeeffeefdface0badd00dcacad0d0eeeeeeee": {
      "balance": "42"
    }
  }
}
%
```

It also caught the fact that you had a key+value pair with no enclosing object.  ☺

Comment: I just have a text file, not json.

Comment: [You contradict yourself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505866/#comment934017_505867).

Comment: It looks like a json but if you read the question I specify that is a text file :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a line after the occurence of "accounts",

```
sed "/accounts/ a\
  \"$ACCOUNT_ADDR\": { \"balance\": \"1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376i\" }
" file
```

(The `"` are escaped, to insert variable)

```
sed "s/^ }$/ \"$ACCOUNT_ADDR\": { \"balance\": \"1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376i\" }\n }/g" file
```

Will replace your `}` line and print two lines.

Run `sed -i ...` for changing the file, in cycle:

```
$  cat file
"accounts": {
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000008": { "builtin": { "name": "alt_bn128_pairing", "activate_at": "0x0", "pricing": { "alt_bn128_pairing": { "base": 100000, "pair": 80000 } } } },
    "0x00Ea169ce7e0992960D3BdE6F5D539C955316432": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376" }
 }

$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 1 5); do
  ACCOUNT_ADDR="account_"$i
  sed -i "/accounts/ a\
      \"$ACCOUNT_ADDR\": { \"balance\": \"1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376i\" }
  " file
done

$ ./script.sh
$ cat file
"accounts": {
"account_5": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376i" }
"account_4": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376i" }
"account_3": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376i" }
"account_2": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376i" }
"account_1": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376i" }
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000008": { "builtin": { "name": "alt_bn128_pairing", "activate_at": "0x0", "pricing": { "alt_bn128_pairing": { "base": 100000, "pair": 80000 } } } },
    "0x00Ea169ce7e0992960D3BdE6F5D539C955316432": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376" }
 }
```

Comment: The first solution partially works for me. However, since I need to add more than one address i repeat the command inside a for cycle, in this way I am able to iterate over all the addresses. 

However, this generates several replicas of the entire json, just updating the first account after the keyword "accounts", and not one unique json with the list of all the accounts.

Comment: I see, just run `sed -i` instead of just `sed `, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every now and and then I like a sed challenge: using `ACCOUNT_ADDR=1234`:

```
sed -n -e '
    x
    $ i\
"'"$ACCOUNT_ADDR"'": {"balance":0},
    2,$ p
    $ { x; p }
' file
```

```
 "accounts": {
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000008": { "builtin": { "name": "alt_bn128_pairing", "activate_at": "0x0", "pricing": { "alt_bn128_pairing": { "base": 100000, "pair": 80000 } } } },
"1234": {"balance":0},
    "0x00Ea169ce7e0992960D3BdE6F5D539C955316432": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376" }
 }
```

This uses the `x` to stash the current line into the hold space to become the "previous" line in the next cycle.

As mentioned elsewhere, use `sed -i` to save the edits in-place

---

You can get the same result by reversing the file and using a simpler sed command:

```
temp=$(mktemp)
tac file | sed '2a\
"'"$ACCOUNT_ADDR"'": {"balance":0},
' | tac > "$temp" && mv "$temp" file
```